# djangorest api not returning human readable values of choice field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am new to DjangoRest and facing one problem, I have a choice field in my model with 3 choices. I want to display the Human readable values when the api the called.

In serializer I am using serializers.ModelSerializer and displaying all the fields from my model class using:-

```
fields = '__all__'
```

In model, I am using 'get_foo_display' method as described in the documentation and using `def __str__(self)` to display the fields.

But still, when this api is called, it is not displaying Human readable values, instead display 'to-do'/'in-process'/'done'.

Djangorest Version:

```
print (rest_framework.VERSION)
3.10.1
```

Python Version

Python 3.7.4

This is my first question in the forum, please let me know if any mistakes made in asking questions.

Thanks in advance.

tried using get_status_display in the serializer, it works for get api and displays the output in human readable format, but then the POST api starts failing with error 'type mismatch'

I am new to DjangoRest and facing one problem, I have a choice field in my model with 3 choices.

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (('to-do', 'Work Not Yet Started'),
          ('in-process', 'Work UnderProgress'),
          ('done', 'Work Completed')
         )
status = models.CharField (choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=10)
```

In Model, I am using:

```
def __str__(self):
   return '{}: {} {} ({})'.format
    (self.id, self.title, self.description, 
             self.get_status_display()
    )
```

serializer code:

```
class Meta:
    model = KanbanCards
    fields = '__all__'
```

Expected result is 'Work Not Yet Started' but getting 'to-do'

Answer (score 2):

DRF supports defining a function called to_representation in the serializer class that overrides one or a set of fields on the read function.

For a more thorough description, please refer to: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

Here's the code snippet that would work in your case:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    ret['status'] = [value for key, value in STATUS_CHOICES if key == ret['status']][0]
    return ret
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks! Since I was using django's `model.TextChoices` class to create my choices class I could do the following to look up the human readable label: `ret['status'] = StatusChoices(ret['status']).label`